# File Won't Run With Specific Name

Tags: windows, windows-10, screensaver

This is a strange issue. It may seem unimportant, but now that I've encountered this I'd at least like to know why it happens or if it's a known bug amongst other files.

I have a screensaver which will not open so long as the name of the screensaver is set to its original name, "Amazing Universe.scr" . If I rename it to anything else, even with a space still in the name, it works. Disabling my antivirus makes no difference, and it does not matter if the screensaver is set as default or not. I can still configure the screensaver, but pressing Preview in the "Change your screen saver" settings dialog, or double clicking the screensaver in the Windows folder, does nothing unless I change its name.

It's just my luck that the screensaver actually creates a log file - but only when it has write permission, which it doesn't have in the Windows folder, and moving the screensaver anywhere else also causes it to work.

Does anyone know why this very odd issue might be happening? I never had this problem on Windows 7, it only occurred after upgrading to Windows 10, and the screensaver was working for a while, so maybe an update broke it.

EDIT
By running the screensaver in an elevated command prompt, I was able to get this console log.

```
19:45:52  [INFO] CD3D9 : Direct3D9 Rendering System created.
19:45:52  [INFO] D3D9: Driver Detection Starts
19:45:52  [INFO] D3D9: Driver Detection Ends
19:45:52  [INFO] D3D9: System Initialization
19:45:52  [ERROR] An exception has been thrown!

-----------------------------------
Details:
-----------------------------------
Error #: 0
Function: CD3D9VideoModeList::item
Description: Invalid videomode index. 
File: .\Source\RenderSystem\engeasy_d3d9videomodelist.cpp
Line: 125
```

Why would this file be denied access to DirectX 9 features?

EDIT AGAIN
The issue seems to occur when hitting the "Preview" button in the "Change your screen saver" interface. As soon as I do that, the screensaver will never run again with the same filename. But why?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I solved it myself after posting the question here. I had the screensaver configured to use 32 bit colour depth, but for some reason it only works with 16. By renaming the file I was changing back the configuration as the name of the screensaver changed, until I installed the screensaver and it would set to 32 bit colour depth again.